# Calculate the half-maximal inhibitory concentration IC50

Tags: r, function, testing

I have a task to create my own code to find IC50 with given in advance C, v1, H, n, and V function. I managed to create the following code:

```
# added inhibitor value
C=c(0,0.3,1.5,3.5,19.5)

# compline inhibitor results vector percentages
v1 = c (0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.25, 0.90)


v1 = v1 + runif(length(v1), min = -0.1, max = 0.1)

# H and n values
H = 1
n = 1


# Define the V() function
V <- function(C, H, n) {
  1 / (1 + (C / H)^n)
}


# Define the x_dense2 vector
x_dense2 = seq(0, 10, by = 0.1)

y_spa2 = V(C, H, n)
# Generate random noise and add it to the observed response values
v1 = v1 + runif(length(v1), min = -0.1, max = 0.1)

# Interpolate the noisy data using linear interpolation
y_dense2 = approx(v1, y_spa2, xout = x_dense2, method = "linear")$y

# Find the x-coordinate where y_dense2 first crosses 0.5
x_cross = x_dense2[which(y_dense2 <= 0.5)[1]]

# The x-coordinate is the IC50 value
IC50 = x_cross


# Plot the interpolated curve
plot(x_dense2, y_dense2, type = "l")

# Add a vertical line at the IC50 value
abline(v = IC50, col = "green")
```

My code gives some results but I'm not sure if it's correct. I don't know how to test it any other way. I have no other data for the IC50. That's why I am asking for help in testing my code and possibly correcting errors if there are any in my code.

Comment: thank for editon Konrad Rudolph

Comment: any help or tips please?

Comment: Again, I'm asking for  help. I'm looking for the opinion/consultation of more experienced forum users regarding my question.

Comment: Can someone help me test this code please?

Comment: Any help is a very important question for me?